# Simulating Correlation attacks on Tor using Shadow

Tags: attacks, traffic-analysis, shadow

Is it possible to simulate correlation attacks on Tor using Shadow? If it's possible what's the easiest way to implement it? If it's not possible, then is there any other simulators that can be used for that purpose?

Thank You

Comment: I can't run TorPS successfully. Can you communicate with me，thanks

Comment: @Izhiwei what exact problem do you have running TorPS?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help but you can do it using tor path simulator.

https://github.com/torps/torps